# Installing python-central

Tags: python

I have the Python central tar.gz file.

I don’t know how to install it. I unzipped it, but now what? After unzipping it I run `./configure`, but I get a *no such file or directory*. Yes, I am in the directory that was created after I unzipped.

I've been trying to use `electrum`, but I get a *ecdsa is not installed* error. I can't install it, because I need `pip`, but I can't install `pip` because it needs `python-central`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are connected to the internet and then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install python-central
```

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: Properly close all other terminals and Ubuntu Software center as well, if it is opened

Comment: i get that error

Comment: Then, restart your computer and then try.

Comment: that does not exists

Answer (score 2):

The package `python-central` seems unavailable in Ubuntu 14.04. One may add [LinuxMint to their sources](https://github.com/elbersb/otr-verwaltung/issues/11) - or download the DEB file, e.g., from [UbuntuUpdates.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_upstream/rebecca/upstream/base/python-central) to install via Sotware Center.